# Makefile exits with fatal error

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a project with following structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── bin
├── include
│   └── reader.h
├── Makefile
├── obj
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    └── reader.cpp

4 directories, 4 files
```

I want to have `.cpp` file in `src/`, headers in `include/` , compile object files in `obj/` and executables in `bin/`. I use GNU make in version 4.1, g++ in version 7.2.0 and Ubuntu 17.10. When I try to build it (I try to use ideas [from here](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/), slightly modified) I get following error:

```
$ make
make: Circular obj/main.o <- obj/main.o dependency dropped.
make: Circular obj/reader.o <- obj/main.o dependency dropped.
make: Circular obj/reader.o <- obj/reader.o dependency dropped.
g++ -c -o obj/obj/reader.o include/reader.h 
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:1:0: fatal error: can’t create precompiled header obj/obj/reader.o: No such file or directory
 /* Copyright (C) 1991-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

compilation terminated.
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'obj/reader.o' failed
make: *** [obj/reader.o] Error 1
```

I am new to makefiles, so I guess it's something very basic. How can I fix this?

**EDIT** I forgot about Makefile`. Here we go:

```
IDIR = include
OBJDIR = obj

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++14 -I$(IDIR)
DEPS = reader.h

_DEPS = reader.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o reader.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(OBJ) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

**EDIT2** After changing language to English I understood the warnings I had. 
 I deleted redundant `$(OBJDIR)` part from `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` directive and ended up with something like this:

```
IDIR = include
OBJDIR = obj

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++14 -I$(IDIR)
DEPS = reader.h

_DEPS = reader.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o reader.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(OBJ) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

and new errors:

```
$ make
make: Circular obj/main.o <- obj/main.o dependency dropped.
make: Circular obj/reader.o <- obj/main.o dependency dropped.
make: Circular obj/reader.o <- obj/reader.o dependency dropped.
g++ -c -o obj/main.o obj/reader.o 
g++: warning: obj/reader.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ -o main obj/main.o obj/reader.o -g -Wall -std=c++14 -Iinclude
g++: error: obj/main.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(OBJ) $(DEPS)` makes no sense. You're saying every object file depends on itself (and also all other object files). That's why make is complaining `Circular obj/main.o <- obj/main.o dependency dropped.`. `$(OBJ)` shouldn't be there.

`$(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)` is broken because `$<` is the first prerequisite, which in this case is `obj/reader.o`. It's like you're trying to compile one object file into another, which makes no sense.

Also, why are you using `$(CFLAGS)` here? You're compiling C++, so it should be `$(CXXFLAGS)` (your code never sets `CFLAGS` anyway).

Your Makefile never mentions any cpp files. This cannot work.

---

I would throw away your Makefile and start with something simple:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++14 -Iinclude

bin/main: obj/main.o obj/reader.o
        $(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $+ $(LDLIBS)

obj/main.o: src/main.cpp include/reader.h
obj/reader.o: src/reader.cpp include/reader.h
```

This should be all you need.

Comment: I needed to add `$(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $+ $(LDLIBS)` after each object file creation to make it run, but I got one step further. It does not seem to see header files. I have a class defined in a header and when I include it in `.cpp` with: `#include "include/reader.h"

Reader::Reader()` I get `g++ -o obj/main.o  src/main.cpp include/reader.h 
src/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: include/reader.h: No such file or directory
 #include "include/reader.h"
`

I can update my question if you wish for more readibility.

Comment: @gonczor For object file creation it should be `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @gonczor ... and that assumes your .cpp files `#include "reader.h"`. If they include `"include/reader.h"`, then I think it should be `-I.` in `CXXFLAGS`.